# Issue on Gift card and cart prices rules

Tags: magento2, discount, validation, gift-card

I've tried couple of hours, but I can't find the solution. I used [Amasty](https://amasty.com/magento-free-gift.html) Gift card, Also I created cart prices rule. when I enter the gift code only, the discount shows validation error. If I enter discount code the gift card shows this error. Check the screen shot. Please advice how to fix this [image]

PHP configuration : 7.0
Magento            : 2.1.5 CM
Gift Card          : 1.0.3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're facing problems with any of our modules, please submit a ticket https://amasty.com/contacts/

For now it's hard to understand the cause of the issue. And it's not entirely clear which particular extension you're using as you are writing about Gift Card but linking to Free Gift, which are different mods.

Comment: Lot of the issue with final payment. The gift amount not accepted by papal or brain tree payment. I tried to contact you. But non of them response prepare. if possible answer here.

Comment: Have you find the ticket of mine ?

Comment: Yes, we found your ticket. You wrote that when a gift card is used, the payment amount in the shopping cart does not change.
Our support manager asked you for some details that are needed to investigate the issue. But he didn't receive any answers from you. He wrote you one more letter today. Please check your email and don't forget to check your spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2.5.1 and installed in year 2020/2021 and this issue still exist.

Its sad that such a basic function dont work. We try to run promo recently and cart price rule work for all products except amasty giftcard.

Amasty Support insist its not a bug and ask for 3 times the price of the plugin to fix this as customization. I find it unacceptable that we cannot discount giftcards if we want to run promotion.

If anybody have a solution on which file in mAgento2 to edit to add in product type please let me know.